# Can two apps be tied so that when one opens or closes, the other does so?

Tags: macos, terminal, automator, script

Can triggers be set up so that when "App A" starts, another "App B" gets started automatically? Ideally, the solution would send a quit message to "App B" when "App A" quits, but the important part is the launch sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a plist like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>test</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>while sleep 5; do
  if pgrep -x Preview; then
    pgrep -x TextEdit || open -jga TextEdit
  else
    pgrep -x TextEdit &amp;&amp; osascript -e 'quit app "TextEdit"'
  fi
done</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then load the plist with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist` or by logging out and back in.

`open -jg` is supposed to open an application hidden and without raising any windows. For some document-based applications like TextEdit, it opens a new visible window if the application is open but has no visible windows.

`pgrep` and the `-j` option for `open` were added in 10.8. The `-j` option is only shown in the help message and not on the man page.